# How to get an item within an object within an array in a map in react

Tags: reactjs

I am currently stuck in a personal project and I can't put the right words in google to find the solution...

I have a map in my code from a collection in a database, this map shows a `<Card />` with info on it like so:

```js
.map((personnage) => (
    <Card
    key={personnage._id}
    id={personnage._id}
    name={personnage.name}
    job={personnage.job.toLowerCase()}
        firstBounty={personnage.bounties[0]?.toLocaleString()} /*Separate the first bounty with space, the ? is to verify if there is a value, else it won't work*/
    lastBounty={personnage.bounties
            .slice(-1)
            .toLocaleString()} // Separate the last Bounty with space
    firstGrade={personnage.grade[0]?.index}
    lastGrade={personnage.grade.slice(-1)?.index}
/>
))
```

the .json would look like

```json
{
  grade: [{ index: 5, name: "something"}, { index: 12, name: "something else"}]
}
```

So I tried to replace `slice(-1).index` by `slice().reverse().index` but it doesn't work... And I can't find the logic behind it...

So I'm just trying to get the last grade of the grade array. And pass the `index` to the `lastGrade` prop.

Thanks for your help kind strangers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of the array.

You need to **substract 1** since the array starts with index **0**

```js
<Card
  ...
  lastGrade={personnage.grade[personnage.grade.length - 1]?.index}
/>
```